# does anyone knows how to solve dependency clash between httpx httpcore and googletrans?

Tags: python, dependency-management, httpx, googletrans

I have a code in which googletrans(4.0) is clashing with httpx and httpcore.

do you have any version combination for working all at same time.

i tried :

1. pip install -U googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
2. then motor lib will give error: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
   module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'NetworkBackend'
   3.Now if i try to update httpcore then googletrans will stop working and asking for correct versions

Comment: Most packages that have dependencies would specify the _exact_ versions of those dependencies, which would get installed when you install the main package with pip. You may have installed httpx separately, and that version isn't compatible with googletrans. Try fully uninstalling httpx, then reinstalling googletrans.